# Casperjs fillXPath https

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

i'm new to casperjs so apologize me if my question is too stupid but i search for about 2 hours on google and didn't find anything to solve my problem.
So i want to open google maps page and fill the search form in it.
Here is my code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
pageSettings: {
javascriptEnabled: true,
loadImages: true,
loadPlugins: true,
userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
}
});

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
var fields = {}

casper.start('https://www.google.fr/maps/', function() {
this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl()); // "http://www.google.fr/"
});

casper.then(function() {
  fields['//*[@id="searchboxinput"]'] = '36 Quai des Orfèvres 75001 Paris'
  casper.test.assertExists(x('.//form[@name="searchbox_form"]'));
  this.fillXPath('form[name="searchbox_form"]', fields, false);
});

casper.run();
```

I right click on the form and inspect element to get the xpath.
Even the assert fail.
I dont understand where i make mistake.
Thanks.

Edit:
I add

```
this.getCurrentUrl()
```

in the casper.start() and i have

```
about:blank
```

It seems that capersjs doesn't want to load https page..
What can I do to bypass this problem.
PS: The API doesn't provide the information I want.

Comment: If this is simply for learning purposes, then you really should switch to another site, because Google delivers a different page depending on user agent string and viewport size.

Comment: i add the user agent from the browser i use, and its doesn't work

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.